# How do I add a api created guest cart to active guest user or how to get quote ID from active guest user

Tags: magento2, api, quote

I have a Magento store and a Wordpress website on the same domain, I want to view edit add and delete products from both sites.

So far I've been able to get the products from the local storage and show them on the WordPress website.

I am able to create a guest cart trough the Magento API and add products to this cart.

So now I need to add the guest cart to the current user on Magento (or get the quote id of the Magento cart in WordPress)

Comment: How you get `products from the session`?

Comment: @AmitBera I'm sorry I meant the local storage!! I'll edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone struggling with the same issue.
I fixed it by setting the session domain to the base domain and then getting the quote id from the magento session.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same. Please give more information

Comment: @LizEipeC
It has been a while but if I remember correctly I had a wp site on site.nl and a magento webshop on shop.site.nl. 

To make sure I can read the session variables from magento in wordpress I had to set the session domain to the root domain (so site.nl instead of shop.site.nl) this way I was able to read the session data from magento in wordpress

Comment: thanks for the reply. I solved the issue by creating an api call and created the orders programmatically from the serve side

Comment: good to hear, I think I tried that as well but ran into the problem that the cart did not persist between wp and magento

Comment: For me requirement  was different I am trying to products from the guest wishlist to cart. so it worked for me.